# How to access network paths from Java on OSX?

Tags: java, macos

I try to access a network folder / UNC path from Java on Mac OSX. On Windows, the following test program works fine (at least one of the tested paths):

```
public class PathTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (String path : Arrays.asList(
                "\\\\myserver\\transfer", "//myserver/transfer", "file://myserver/transfer", "smb://myserver/transfer")) {

            File f = new File(path);
            System.out.println(path + ": " + f.getAbsolutePath() + ", " + f.exists());

            Path p = Paths.get(path);
            System.out.println(path + ": " + p.toAbsolutePath() + ", " + Files.exists(p));
        }
    }
}
```

on Mac OS it fails to reach the folders:

```
\\myserver\transfer: /Users/tim/IdeaProjects/PathTest/\\myserver\transfer, false
//myserver/transfer: /myserver/transfer, false
file://myserver/transfer: /Users/tim/IdeaProjects/PathTest/file://myserver/transfer, false
smb://myserver/transfer: /Users/tim/IdeaProjects/PathTest/smb://myserver/transfer, false
```

When I use Finder, I can access the Folder (using the Guest user), by using "smb://myserver/transfer". What's wrong?

**EDIT** added NIO.2 test

Comment: `smb://xxx` is not a valid pathname for the `File` class, see the API (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html). On UNIX is must always start with `/`. On Windows you can also use UNC pathnames. So Anthony's answer is correct.

Comment: What about Java NIO.2?

Comment: You can test yourself: `Path path = Paths.get(URI.create("smb://myserver/transfer"));` `Files.exists(path).` but I had no lucky with the default `FileSystemProvider`, and, to the best of my knowledge, there is no  pluggable CIFS aware `FileSystemProvider` available.

Comment: UNC is a Windows-ism, not sure where the expectation of it working on OS X came from. Natively OS X only mounts network drives using VFS. Finder will do that automatically when fed a `smb:` path, but that's Finder, not an OS-level feature.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly: I added an NIO.2 test, no luck

Comment: @millimoose: I realize that, however Java's file API could abstract stuff like this. Secondly, samba ("smb://...") should work just fine, at least it does from Finder.

Comment: @TimBüthe It could, but it doesn't. Java's file IO takes the lowest-common-denominator approach and likely just uses whatever is available to portable C whenever possible. It just so happens that accessing SMB filesystems is wired into Windows at a much lower level than it is in OS X, so Java takes advantage of it there. Opening a `smb:` *URL* would work if Java came with its own implementation of that protocol, since URL scheme handling doesn't strictly depend on OS support. Except there's also no expectation of that being the case. (My guess it you only get the usual `file:` and `http:`.)

Comment: @millimoose in my understanding, Java does not take the lowest-common-denominator approach, especially not NIO.2. NIO.2 provides methods for dealing with hard- and soft links, as well as file permissions and so forth.

Comment: @TimBüthe It'd still have to special-case OS X and call whatever API is available to mount a SMB volume. Not saying it'd be *wrong* for such a special case to be there, but that's really up to the JDK people to decide, and it's not an obvious feature to have either.

Comment: @TimBüthe Hi I am placing the same problem, if you have any solution please post it here

Comment: @Pragnani Anthony's answer is right so I accepted it right now. Java doesn't seem to have an out of the box solution for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either mount the partition and access it as any local directory or use a specialized library such as [JCIFS](http://jcifs.samba.org/) or [Apache Commons VFS](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/).